# Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi disconnecting

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

I'm having trouble with the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Wifi connection. This just happens after installation of Ubuntu 20.04. ,other PCs or smartphones do not have any wifi problems. The System is up to date.

Problem:
After the boot, I dont have any problems with the wifi. After a while - 45-60min - the wifi notification remarks problems to connect, than I can*t see the wifi conection anymore. Suspend or even reboot doesn't bring back the wifi conection. I do have to Shut down, after that the wifi works again.

sudo lshw -C network - network broken shows:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   version: 30
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:b431c000-b431ffff
```

sudo lshw -C network - network working shows:

```
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 30
   serial: d8:f2:ca:c3:fd:bb
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-52-generic firmware=46.6bf1df06.0 ip=192.168.178.79 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:16 memory:b431c000-b431ffff
```

Using Asus Zenbook Pro 14 UX480

sudo dmidecode -s bios-version:

```
UX450FDX.307
```

Do you have any suggestions?

sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager

```
Okt 29 16:30:19 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603985419.6248] dhcp4 (wlo1):
Okt 29 16:30:19 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603985419.6391] device (wlo1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Okt 29 16:30:19 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603985419.6478] device (wlo1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Okt 29 16:30:19 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603985419.6487] device (wlo1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Okt 29 16:30:19 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603985419.6503] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Okt 29 16:30:19 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603985419.6558] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Okt 29 16:30:19 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603985419.6562] policy: set 'Tattoine' (wlo1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Okt 29 16:30:19 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603985419.6578] device (wlo1): Activation: successful, device activated.
Okt 29 16:30:20 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603985420.9975] agent-manager: agent[d0f7d3443eddf950,:1.41/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Okt 29 16:30:21 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603985421.3174] dhcp6 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Okt 29 16:30:21 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603985421.3238] dhcp6 (wlo1): option dhcp6_name_servers   => 'fd00::5e49:79ff:fe2d:c0b3'
Okt 29 16:30:21 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603985421.3238] dhcp6 (wlo1): state changed unknown -> bound
Okt 29 16:30:23 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603985423.5537] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Okt 29 17:42:20 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <warn>  [1603989740.1534] sup-iface[0x56005ed2d2e0,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Okt 29 17:42:20 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603989740.1545] device (wlo1): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Okt 29 17:42:20 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603989740.1840] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
Okt 29 17:42:20 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603989740.1840] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed bound -> done
Okt 29 17:42:20 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603989740.1846] dhcp6 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
Okt 29 17:42:20 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603989740.1846] dhcp6 (wlo1): state changed bound -> done
Okt 29 17:42:20 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603989740.2083] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Okt 29 17:42:20 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603989740.2130] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: >
Okt 29 17:42:20 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1603989740.2148] radio killswitch /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill0 disappeared
Okt 29 17:42:20 skywalker NetworkManager[870]: <warn>  [1603989740.2153] dns-sd-resolved[36b788391fdebc00]: send-updates failed to update systemd-resolved: GDBus.Error:org.
```

connection disconnected (reason -3), do you know, what reason -3 is and how to solve it?

Comment: Look at the logs. `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: see post below with specific output